# Youtube API - retrieve single video info - JS works fine, PHP gives restriction error

Tags: php, jquery, video, youtube-api

I wrote this code

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=MY_SECRET_KEY&part=snippet,statistics&id=yZj_EC8C5Ng';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://niezaleznylublin.pl/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$obiekt=json_decode($json);
echo '<h1>'.$obiekt->items[0]->snippet->title.'</h1>';
echo '<img src="'.$obiekt->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->standard->url.'"/>';
echo '<p>'.$obiekt->items[0]->snippet->description.'</p><br />';
echo '<h3>TAGI:</h3>';
echo '<p>';
foreach ($obiekt->items[0]->snippet->tags as $items)    {
    echo $items.', ';
}

echo'</p>';
echo $obiekt->items[0]->snippet->liveBroadcastContent;


echo '<br /><br /><br />';var_dump($obiekt);
```

It works well until my Youtube project is open to use with any site. When i try to add restriction to site from which i run my script ...
*niezaleznylublin.pl/**(one asterisk here)
 var_dump object contains this data ...

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["domain"]=> string(11) "usageLimits" ["reason"]=> string(16) "ipRefererBlocked" ["message"]=> string(254) "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed." ["extendedHelp"]=> string(37) "https://console.developers.google.com" } } ["code"]=> int(403) ["message"]=> string(254) "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed." } }
```

Funny thing is that when I'm trying JQuery script from site below everything is working fine with or without page restriction

http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html

Comment: Have you tried to put Referer header into your curl request? I suppose youtube is not able to deteremine where does request come from when using PHP's curl.

Comment: Yes i did. I forgot that this copy of the code doesnt contain that. Updated

Comment: Open inspector in Chrome, fire up jQuery request, switch to inspector's network tab and find the request. Under context menu of that request you'll have "copy as curl" option. This may give you a hint what are you missing in your PHP's curl. You may also want to add this curl command to your question.

Answer (score 0):

LOL this is odd. I tried script today, havent change anything and works well now. Either some kind of propagation is involved here or indeed Google guys watch those youtube-api topics as they claim in help center.

Nevertheless thanks for all responses.